# Why doesn't my PWA use service workers when it's launched from the homescreen?

Tags: mobile, safari, service-worker, homescreen

I'm upgrading my app from AppCache to service workers via Google's workbox.

**Results:**

- Chrome

  - test setup: devtools
  - notes: runs great, haven't tested with chrome on android
- iPhone:

  - test setup: put phone in airplain mode
  - open in browser: works pretty well but it does show a native popup warning that the page cannot be opened because the network can't be reached. App loads behind this warning and is usable after that.
  - open from homescreen: same native popup warning that the page cannot be loaded because the network cannot be reached. App does *not* load in the background.

When I reconnect to the network and load the app from my homescreen, it hits my server to get sw.js and the precache-manifest but it doesn't grab any other assets *and* it boots up fine.

So, why can't I run my app offline anymore when I launch it from the homescreen? Is this a bug with service workers and I should revert to App Cache or has anyone else gotten this to work?

Thanks!

**Further Debugging:**

I've connected Safari's devtools to my iPhone and now I'm seeing the following in the console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (precache-manifest.74ba0448495d9599f20233bb79d47c66.js, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (sw.js, line 0)
```

So, it's failing hard trying to load the service worker and it's precache-manifest.

I have another app that still falls back to AppCache and it shows a similar error about not being able to load sw.js but it is completely useable (I can even launch it from the homescreen when my phone is in airplane mode).